# Content-type of response is set to application/xml after adding xml support

Tags: spring, spring-boot

Another wierd problem of mine.
I had controller for rest api:

```
@RestController()
@RequestMapping("/api/project")
public class ProjectController{
    @PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('ROLE_USER')")
    @GetMapping(value = "/{id}/severitychart")
    public ResponseEntity<HashMap<String,Long>> showSeverityChart(@PathVariable("id")Long id) {
        return projectService.showSeverityChart(id);
    }
}
```

and it was working great, returining `JSON` response.

Later I had to add proccessing of `XML` - nothing fancy just simple parsing of given `XML` message and storing it into database. Still all responses should be mapped to JSON`it was done using`JAXBContext`

from now on each response of API call return XML structured object with header `content-type: application/xml`

is it possible to keep service as t is and still use default JSON mapping?

I would like not to put `produces = "application/json"` on each endpoint...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@EnableWebMvc
@Configuration
public class WebConfiguration implements WebMvcConfigurer {
    @Override
    public void configureContentNegotiation(final ContentNegotiationConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.defaultContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
    }
}
```